# Why does Android Studio delete dependencies listed in build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Earlier this week Android Studio started randomly deleting dependencies from my build.gradle file whenever I create a new file.
Is there a particular order that's expected?
My dependencies section looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':ParallaxScroll')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile group: 'com.squareup.picasso', name: 'picasso', version: '2.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.squareup.retrofit', name: 'retrofit', version: '1.4.1'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'    
}
```

When I create a new activity in the project it ends up looking like this (this happens every time):

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':ParallaxScroll')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile group: 'com.squareup.picasso', name: 'picasso', version: '2.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.squareup.retrofit', name: 'retrofit', version: '1.4.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

It took a little while to figure out what was happening.

Which of the two compile formats I'm using is correct? Is this potentially causing issues? It wasn't an issue until this week.

I can of course restore my dependencies but this doesn't explain why AS is deleting things all the time.

I'm also concerned about both support libraries being included. As far as I know I'm using only v4 stuff. Is using both bad practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug that will be fixed in 0.5.9. You can track it here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60749

In the meantime, as a workaround, just create new activities by hand, or save off the contents of the build file before creating them through the wizard.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response. I'll carry on copying it, or retrieving it from source control when I forget.